Recently replaced fixed gear drive train and the chain has stretched 1/8th inch over 24 links in under 200 miles
I have a wabi classic. Over the last few months it became apparent that the drive train needed to be replaced. I would replace a chain and it would be badly stretched after a week or two (~100 miles). Upon inspection I could see that the rear sprocket was badly "shark fin" shaped. The chainring's wear was not as apparent.
I bought a new chainring, cog and chain and installed them all myself. Everything appeared to be running smoothly and I cleaned and lubricated the chain after a week of light riding.
Now is only a week later. After a decent amount of riding but probably just about 200 total miles the chain is measuring 12 and 1/8ths inch at the 24th link when checked with a ruler. I'm not sure how the chain checking tool metric works but the bike shop told me it's .75 or something.
Brand new components and I just have to leave it in the garage until I get a replacement. The current components are Euro-Asia Imports rear sprocket, FSA chainring, and KMC chain.
I really don't know what went wrong here, except to say that the chain is filthy. I cleaned it a week ago but it looks worse than anything I've ever seen at the moment. Could an extremely dirty chain fail in the way I have described? Could there be something wrong with the cranks or bracket or something else?
Thank you.
